# Beginner Question about ReactJS error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have tried out several other answers with this same issue and i still cant figure out why i keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".
Any help would be appreciated.

The code is:

```
    import React from 'react';
import * as $ from 'jquery';


class TeamRaceDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            teamResults: [],
            loading: true
        }
          this.getTeamResults = this.getTeamResults.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getTeamResults();
    }

    getTeamResults(){
        const id = this.props.teamid;
        var url = 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/constructors/' + id + '/results.json'; 
        //console.log(url);
        $.get(url, (teamResultData) => {
            //console.log(resultData);
            this.setState({ teamResults: teamResultData, loading:false });
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading === true){
            return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
        }

        var teamResults = this.state.teamResults.MRData.RaceTable.Races.Results;
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Round</th>
                            <th>Grand prix</th>
                            <th>{this.state.teamResults.position}</th>
                            <th>{this.state.teamResults.grid}</th>
                            <th>Points</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {teamResults.map((race, i) => <TeamResults teamRacesData = {race} key={i}/>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>              
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TeamResults extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.teamRacesData.round}</td>
            <td>{this.props.teamRacesData.Circuit.circuitName}</td>
            <td>{this.props.teamRacesData.Results[0].Constructor.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.teamRacesData.Results[0].grid}</td>
            <td>{this.props.teamRacesData.Results[0].position}</td>
        </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default TeamRaceDetails;
```

Comment: Is it possible that `teamResultData`(responseData) from your api is not an array?

Comment: `teamResults` is `undefined` when you call `map`. That is what the exception is about.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `this.getTeamResults()` in componentDidMount and this API is async
. So, in the first time of render `this.state.teamResults.MRData.RaceTable.Races.Results` is undefined. In the second of render, you can got this data.
Try this code:

```
<tbody>
     {teamResults && teamResults.map((race, i) => // make sure teamResults defined
          <TeamResults teamRacesData = {race} key={i}/>
     )}
</tbody>
```

When you use map operator to render a list in react, should be check same as above
Or you can defined default parameter like this:

```
var teamResults = this.state.teamResults.MRData.RaceTable.Races.Results || [];
// teamResults always is an array, will not have an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `teamResults` is not an array.  You can mitigate by assigning a default value:

```
var teamResults = this.state.teamResults.MRData.RaceTable.Races.Results || [];
return (
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Round</th>
                    <th>Grand prix</th>
                    <th>{this.state.teamResults.position}</th>
                    <th>{this.state.teamResults.grid}</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {teamResults.map((race, i) => <TeamResults teamRacesData = {race} key={i}/>)}
            </tbody>
        </table>              
    </div>
);
```